# when should I create a new workspace

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just finished beginner tutorials. In the tutorial, we create a catkin_ws. Now I am trying to do some further projects, but I have no idea that do I need to create a new workspace for new project or just create new package in old workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286270/when-should-i-create-a-new-workspace/) by [Jeffery](https://answers.ros.org/users/34274/jeffery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there is a single "best" answer to this: some people like to keep all of their packages in a single workspace, others like to group packages that they use for particular projects into separate workspaces.

Neither is necessarily better than the other.

Personally I keep separate workspaces for just about everything, and use [workspace overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) whenever I need certain packages in other workspaces.

---

Edit:

> Thank you for answering. So if I keep all packages in one workspace, whenever I use catkin_make to build packages, it will build all my packages, but usually I don't really need other packages.

That could be one reason to have multiple workspaces, yes.

On the other hand, [catkin_tools](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) supports [profiles](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html) that allow you to configure [black and whitelists](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#whitelisting-and-blacklisting-packages). If you'd want, you could have a workspace with 1000 packages, while still only building 3 of them (for instance).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffery](https://answers.ros.org/users/34274/jeffery/) on 2018-03-22**:
Thank you for answering. So if I keep all packages in one workspace, whenever I use catkin_make to build packages, it will build all my packages, but usually I don't really need other packages.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2018-03-22**:
That's been my reason for using catkin_tools. I have that one repo with a lot of packages some broken that I don't need. Catkin build only build the ones I need :)